# What's this function doing?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $\phi$ be a group-valued function with domain $P$. That is for each $p \in P$, $\phi(p)$ is a group. This is called a family of groups parametrized by $P$. We will denote $\phi(p)$ by $(G_p, ∗_p)$.
Now denote $\{f: P \rightarrow \cup_{p\in P}G_p:f(p) \in G_p\}$ by $Q$

Am I correct in assuming that for each element '$p$' of the domain, we are getting a element of a group? Depending on what $p$ you use, depends on what group you get, depending on what function you use, determines which element of the group you get? That is, $f(p)$ and $g(p)$ return different values of $G_p$?

We wish to define an operation $∗$ on $Q$. Given $f \in Q$ and $g \in Q$ we need to define $f ∗ g \in Q$, that is we need to define $(f ∗ g)(p)$. We set $(f ∗ g)(p) = f(p) ∗_p g(p)$. Since all of the $G_p, ∗_p$
are groups we have $(f ∗ (g ∗ h))(p) = f(p)(g(p) ∗_p h(p)) = (f(p) ∗_p g(p)) = f ∗ (g ∗ h)(p)$ so $(f ∗ g) ∗ h = f ∗ (g ∗ h)$, that is $Q, ∗$ is associative.

Okay so we are defining an operation on functions, which is the same as defining an operation on group values, am I correct? Can't I just prove all the properties of groups trivially, because the function gives you a value of a group? And I assume that each element of the group can get mapped to.

Comment: $f(p)$ and $g(p)$ don't *necessarily* map to different elements of $G_p$. For example, $f$ might pick out the identity element in $G_p$, and $g$ might pick out the identity element for all $G_p$ except say $G_q$. Then $f$ and $g$ are different functions but $f(p)=g(p)$ for all $p$ except $p=q$.

Comment: And second, the group properties follow trivially only once you've *defined* $(f*g)(p)$. Making the correct definition (as you do) is where the work comes in: that's what allows you to inherit all the group properties in a well-defined way.